# Unable to instantiate service

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, service

I'm trying to play sound in the background and show the error msg

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.playsoundbackground, PID: 17234
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.example.playsoundbackground.BackgroundSoundService: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<com.example.playsoundbackground.BackgroundSoundService> is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.AppComponentFactory>
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3941)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:220)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1876)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<com.example.playsoundbackground.BackgroundSoundService> is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.AppComponentFactory>
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateService(AppComponentFactory.java:129)
at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateService(CoreComponentFactory.java:66)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3936)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:220) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1876) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)

my service code

```
class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {

    // MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "onBind", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //  mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
        //     mediaPlayer.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        //    mediaPlayer.setVolume(100, 100);
        //    mediaPlayer.start();
        Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //     mediaPlayer.start();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing Bohemian Rashpody in the Background", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return startId;
    }




    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //mediaPlayer.stop();
        Toast.makeText(this, "onDestroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // mediaPlayer.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
    }
}
```

code for call

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BackgroundSoundService.class);
        startService(intent);
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.playsoundbackground">

    <application
        android:allowBackup = "true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".BackgroundSoundService"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Your `BackgroundSoundService` class must be `public`.

Comment: Those new logs are unrelated to the original Exception shown. That `IllegalAccessException` is solved by making your `BackgroundSoundService` `public`. If you're having another issue, please post a new question for it.

Comment: I solve this error when making service class public